# custom django-admin commands - AttributeError: 'Command' object has no attribute 'stdout'

Tags: django, django-manage.py

Following the example of writing a custom django-admin command [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/), I've created the following custom command:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError

class Command(BaseCommand):
    args = ''
    help = 'Test command'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        self.stdout.write("Hello World!")
```

Surprisingly, I receive the following stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\My Documents\Dev\MyProject\svn\trunk\dj_project\manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 218, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "D:\My Documents\Dev\MyProject\svn\trunk\dj_project\..\dj_project\dj_app\management\commands\mytest.py", line 8, in handle
    self.stdout.write("Hello World!")
AttributeError: 'Command' object has no attribute 'stdout'
```

How come? This is a very basic custom command that as far as I understand conforms to the example.

I'm using django 1.2.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the mapping to `self.stdout` is a very new change in Django's trunk version, committed in May. If you're running the 1.2 release or earlier, this won't work - and you should be using [the earlier documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/custom-management-commands/).

Comment: I'm running django 1.2.1 so still need an answer. Will update the question.

Comment: I don't know why my answer wasn't satisfactory. Django 1.2.1 was released on May 24, this change was made on June 6.

Comment: @Jonathan: just replace "self.stdout.write" with "print". @Daniel I think your answer would benefit from mentioning the actual fix. But +1 because it helped me with my problem :)

Answer (score 20):

Since this is the first hit on Google I'll write another solution to another problem with the same error message:
If your class Command implements __init__, it has to call __init__ of the superclass.

This will work:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

class Command(BaseCommand):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Command, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        ... do stuff
```

This won't work:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

class Command(BaseCommand):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       ... do stuff
```

Comment: This worked for me, the current correct answer is too old now

Answer (score 5):

There are two easy solutions here. The simple one is to simply convert all of your `self.stdout` lines to `print` statements instead.

That's an OK solution and you can do it.

The better solution, since `self.stdout` is set up in the `execute()` method, is to...run the `execute()` method.

So instead of:

```
Command().handle()
```

Do:

```
Command().execute()
```

That'll set up the `self.stdout` variable correctly and you'll be off and running.

Comment: This answer should be picked as hte best answer!

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion.
Can anyone confirm is there any real difference between handle and execute? I have just changed my handle definition to execute and i am getting the desired result. But little concern is there any actual benefit of using handle in place of execute.